# Unable to delete a private service connection using gcloud CLI command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-vpc

When I try to delete a private service connection using gcloud CLI, I'm getting an error message saying Producer services (Eg: CloudSQL) are still using the connection. There are no GCP resources created in this new GCP project.

```
dineshsonachalam@macbook iac % gcloud services vpc-peerings delete --network=default --service=servicenetworking.googleapis.com

ERROR: (gcloud.services.vpc-peerings.delete) The operation resulted in a failure - "Failed to delete connection: Producer services (Eg: CloudSQL, Cloud MemStore etc) are still using this connection"
```

But I was able to delete the private service connection using the Google Console UI. It would be very helpful if someone shared how to delete a private service connection using gcloud CLI.

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible that you deleted a related service like the one mentioned right before trying the command from CLI?
It might be just a timing issue, and when you reached the console the related service was gone (hence you succeeded)

Comment: It seems to be not a timing issue. I tested this scenario many times with long time intervals.

Answer (score 1):

I replicated the same scenario and I was able to [delete the private connection through GCloud](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-services-access#gcloud_5) by using:

```
gcloud services vpc-peerings delete \
        --service=servicenetworking.googleapis.com \
        --network=VPC_NETWORK \
        --project=PROJECT_ID
```